# composer set a git repository as type component

Tags: symfony, github, composer-php

I'm trying to install some external JS libraries located in Github in a SF2 project with composer.json.

composer.json:

```
{
"name": "myproject",
"license": "my project",
"type": "project",
"description": "my project",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
},
"repositories": {
    "medium-editor" : {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "daviferreira/medium-editor",
            "type": "component",
            "version": "master",
            "source": {
                "url": "git://github.com/daviferreira/medium-editor.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "master"
            },
            "extra": {
                "component": {
                    "scripts": [
                        "dist/js/medium-editor.min.js"
                    ],
                    "styles": [
                        "dist/css/medium-editor.min.css",
                        "dist/css/themes/*.min.css"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "require": {
                "robloach/component-installer": "*"
            }
        }
    },
    "classList" : {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "eligrey/classList.js",
            "type": "component",
            "version": "master",
            "source": {
                "url": "git://github.com/eligrey/classList.js.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "master"
            },
            "extra": {
                "component": {
                    "scripts": [
                        "classList.min.js"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "require": {
                "robloach/component-installer": "*"
            }
        }
    }
},
"require": {
    ...

    "daviferreira/medium-editor" : "dev-master",
    "eligrey/classList.js" : "dev-master"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
},    
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin",
    "component-dir": "web/components"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-assets-install": "symlink",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
    }
}
}
```

The libraries are downloaded but...
I'm expecting that composer will create, with the "robloach/component-installer" dependency, a copy of the files specified in "extra" of the "component" type package to the "web/component" directory, but it doesn't.

What's wrong with my config? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading more carefully the [robloach plugin documentation](https://github.com/RobLoach/component-installer#packages-without-composer-support), I've tried again and finally found a solution. The problem was that I probably had made a lot of "composer update" with different configs and was obliged **to remove / reinstall the packages** to make it work! So the original config post in the question is the **good one**...

I put it again to be sure!

```
    "medium-editor" : {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "require": {
                "robloach/component-installer": "*"
            },
            "name": "daviferreira/medium-editor",
            "type": "component",
            "version": "master",
            "source": {
                "url": "git://github.com/daviferreira/medium-editor.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "master"
            },                
            "extra": {
                "component": {
                    "scripts": [
                        "dist/js/medium-editor.min.js"
                    ],
                    "styles": [
                        "dist/css/medium-editor.min.css",
                        "dist/css/themes/*.min.css"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

And for sure, don't forget to add the Robloach component in the "require" libraries:

```
        "robloach/component-installer": "dev-master",
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use bower for fetching frontend libraries. Composer was created for managing php libs dependencies. It is importand to separate this layers because it's the easiest solution to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Try [PHP Composer Asset Manager](http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/package/8429/post/1-Using-Composer-to-Install-JavaScript-CSS-and-Images-Under-the-Web-Document-Directory.html) package with composer if the problem persist i think you should  execute the command manualy:

app/console assets:install .

Comment: I've take a look on this package, and it's remind me that's the asset management is not a built-in composer functionnality. I already use a "component asset manager" which is https://github.com/RobLoach/component-installer. I've read more carefully the doc and found my mistake. Thanks for your help.